# How do you create a hash in a ruby function that can be passed as an argument to another function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, stripe-payments

### Ruby Stripe

I'm trying to interface with the Ruby Stripe library, specifically with the subscription_update function as documented here: https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_subscription

This is what the syntax looks like:

```
c = Stripe::Customer.retrieve("cus_2BWdBuTAE3HboP")
c.update_subscription(:plan => "basic", :prorate => true)
```

### Implementing Rails Model

I'm implementing a rails model that can interface with the ruby library.  Since this api will update my subscription with nil values (that will over ride the defaults), I need a function that will crawl the writable attributes and create an array of only the attributes that are not nil that I can pass to this update_subscription function.

Here's what I have now:

```
  def get_non_nil_update_attributes
    attributes = Array.new([ :plan, :trial_end, :quantity, :coupon, :prorate ])
    return_attributes = {}

    attributes.each do |attribute|
      if !self.send( attribute ).nil?
        return_attributes[attribute] = self.send( attribute)
      end
    end

    return return_attributes
  end
```

I would like to just call this:

`c.update_subscription( mymodel.get_non_nil_update_attributes )`

But I get an error that I'm not passing in the plan param.  At the console my output if this function is:

```
[{:plan=>"7"}, {:trial_end=>"bla"}]
```

I know this is a simply ruby question but how do I make this output just
`:plan => "7", :trial_end => "bla"` to pass into my function?

Comment: Is the output you posted from `get_non_nil_update_attributes`, or from `update_subscription`?

Comment: The output needs to come from the get_non_nil_update_attributes and be passed to update_subscription.

Answer (score 0):

`get_non_nil_update_attributes` can't return an array as it exists in your post, so something else is going on.

As an aside, you can simplify this method quite a bit:

```
def get_non_nil_attributes(attributes = [:plan, :trial_end, :quantity, :coupon, :prorate])
  all_attributes = Hash[*attributes.zip(attributes.map {|a| send a})]
  all_attributes.select {|k, v| v.present? }
end
```